# Meaning of "trait" in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, glm, categorical-data, multi-level, mcmc

Like in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156683/when-and-why-do-i-have-to-use-trait-for-multinomial-multilevel-models-with-mcm) I'm struggling with the notation of `MCMCglmm`, especially what is meant by `trait`. My code ist the following

```
library("MCMCglmm")

set.seed(123)
y <- sample(letters[1:3], size = 100, replace = TRUE)
x <- rnorm(100)
id <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
dat <- data.frame(y, x, id)

mod <- MCMCglmm(fixed = y ~ x, random = ~us(x):id,
            data = dat,
            family = "categorical")
```

Which gives me the error message `For error structures involving catgeorical data with more than 2 categories pleasue use trait:units or variance.function(trait):units.` (!sic). If I would generate dichotomous data by `letters[1:2]`, everything would work fine. So what is meant by this error message in general and "trait" in particular?

---

**Edit 2016-09-29:**
From [the linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156683/when-and-why-do-i-have-to-use-trait-for-multinomial-multilevel-models-with-mcm) I copied `rcov = ~ us(trait):units` into my call of `MCMCglmm`. And from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q3/004006.html I took (and slightly modified it) the prior 
`list(R = list(V = diag(2), fix = 1), G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(2), nu = 1, alpha.mu = c(0, 0), alpha.V = diag(2) * 100)))`. Now my model actually gives results:

```
MCMCglmm(fixed = y ~ 1 + x, random = ~us(1 + x):id, 
         rcov = ~ us(trait):units, prior = prior, data = dat,
         family = "categorical")
```

But still I've got a lack of understanding what is meant by `trait` (and what by `units` and the notation of the prior, and what is `us()` compared to `idh()` and ...).

**Edit 2016-11-17:**
I think `trait` is synoym to "target variable" or "response" in general or `y` in this case. In the formula for `random` there is nothing on the left side of `~` ["because the response is known from the fixed effect specification."](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf) So the rational behind specifiying that `rcov` needs `trait:units` could be that it is alread defined by the `fixed` formula, what `trait` is (`y` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

`units` is the response variable value, and `trait` is the response variable name, which corresponds to the categories. By specifying `rcov = ~us(trait):units`, you are allowing the residual variance to be heterogeneous across "traits" (response categories) so that all elements of the residual variance-covariance matrix will be estimated.

In Section 5.1 of Hadfield's MCMCglmm Course Notes (`vignette("CourseNotes", "MCMCglmm")`) you can read an explanation for the reserved variables `trait` and `units`.