# What are `trait:units` and `variance.function(trait):units` in `MCMCglmm`?

Tags: r, statistics, glm, bayesian, mcmc

I am trying to perform a `MCMCglmm` of the kind

```
df=data.frame(y=rep(c(0:2),each=12),x=rnorm(3*12))
MCMCglmm(data=df,fixed=y~x, family="categorical")
```

and I get the error message

```
For error structures involving catgeorical data with more than 2 categories pleasue use trait:units or variance.function(trait):units.
```

I had a quick look at [Jarrod Hadfield's course notes](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/MCMCglmm/vignettes/CourseNotes.pdf) but did not find much specification about this notation and its meaning.

What does the notations `trait:units` and `variance.function(trait):units` mean? How would one typically use them?

I welcome you to for example consider the command

```
 m <- MCMCglmm(LetVerb ~ -1 + trait + trait:(Channel + CrSem + MS),
random = ~us(trait):Vinf, rcov = ~ us(trait):units, data = letting,
family = "categorical", prior = priors, verbose = TRUE, burnin =
10000, nitt = 60000, thin = 50)
```

from the third page of this [tutorial](http://www.natalialevshina.com/Documents/MCMCglmm_Tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your question? Having the same issue.

Comment: I would not be able to elaborate an answer as much of MCMCglmm internal mechanism is still very obscure to me but I managed to fix my problem. I ended up with a prior like `prior <- list(R = list(V=diag(n-1),nu=0.02,fix = 1)) `, where `n` is the number of levels of the response variable. The run is then `MCMCglmm(
  data=myData,
  fixed= Response ~ trait:(expl1) + trait:(expl2),
  rcov=~us(trait):units,
  family="categorical",prior = prior)`

Answer (score 0):

For the notation question, see my answer to a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749489/meaning-of-trait-in-mcmcglmm/45593151#45593151).

All the answers to your questions are actually in Jarrod Hadfield's course notes. You will need to read up on the specification of residual variances for multinomial models in Section 5. But briefly, the option `rcov = ~ us(trait):units` allows to model an unconstrained residual variance structure, i. e., the residual variances for different response categories can be thereby modeled heteroscedastically (with different variances for different categories) and non-spherically (allowing any pairwise category residual covariances to be non-zero).